# Ionic 4 web project on an intranet

Tags: ionic4

I develop an ionic 4 web project on an intranet.
On my computer it works fine. Now I am going to upload everything to a server, as part of an intranet web project.

which folders should I upload, src and all subfolders?

then the file is index.html? my initial file is home.page.html.

how do i run it? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To deploy your app, you need to build it first. From the project root of your Ionic 4 project,

```
$ ionic build --prod
```

This will build up the necessary files in a folder called www. Now copy everything from www into your server. Set the entry file to index.html. This is the simplest possible way that I'm aware of.

If you want to look into a PWA, that's also possible. Since you say you're hosting locally, there might not be any point really, but nonetheless, you need to un-comment the script for your service worker inside index.html. It should be something like:

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
  }
</script>
```

Here's a few links I noted down on the subject:
https://blog.ionicframework.com/how-to-make-pwas-with-ionic/
https://blog.ionicframework.com/customizing-ionic-apps-for-web-mobile/
I remember also seeing a one hour long Webinar : “Progressive Web App & Ionic How to and Why?” Decide for yourself if it's for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare a build to deploy it somewhere, you don't want to just run it on a remote computer like you do on your local machine with command line.

It's not clear in your question what kind of app you are building exactly but you should search for "Ionic Deployment" to find some matching documentation.

If you would be building a PWA, then follow this [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/pwa)